# JavaScript object value modification

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using JavaScript (Google Apps Script to be precise) and I'm having some trouble with objects.

I have a var, formData, which is full of data passed back from an HTML form. I can happily access the values like this; exhibitions is the name of a select element;

```
formData.exhibitions.value
```

But I want to change the value from "*" to "ALL". I have tried all the following;

```
formData.exhibitions.value = "ALL"
formData["exhibitions"] = "ALL"
formData.element["exhibitons"] = "ALL"
```

and a few other versions of the above but nothing alters the value.

edit- cut down code, HTML form

```
<form>
Exhibition search <select id="exhibitionList" name ="exhibition">
       <option value="*">All</option>
       <option value="shoes">shoes</option>
       </select>
<input type = "button" value ="Item Search" onclick="printSearch(this.form)"/>
</form>
```

and the function is

```
printSearch(formData){
if(formData.exhibition.value != "*"){
whereData.push(exhibition+"='"+formData.exhibition.value+"'");
}else{formData.set('exhibition','ALL');}
}
```

everything works fine I just can't seem to change the value past the ELSE statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do can't work. The value of a `<select>` has to be the value of one of its `<option>` elements. This is because the value is actually stored in the select's `selectedIndex` property. When you assign to `formData.exhibition.value`, it searches the options for one whose value matches this, and then sets `formData.exhibition.selectedIndex` to its position. If there's no match, it fails and doesn't change the value.

Since you have no `<option value="ALL">` element, trying to set the value to that must fail.

Comment: tried and all I'm getting back is that formData.set is not a function

Comment: I assumed `formData` was created with `new FormData`. How did you create it?

Comment: formData created by the function that is run when the data is passed by the submit button on the form; onclick="function(this.form)"

Comment: HOW is it created in that function?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the full function.

Comment: the function in the script which is run creates formData from the form submission; function(formData){ }. Then formData.name.value is used to get the data out

Comment: So `formData` is actually the form element in the DOM, not a Javascript object.

Comment: `exhibitions` is a `<select>` element, right? Is there an `<option value="ALL">` in it?

Comment: That's exactly right. Sorry I my terminology is still poor.

Comment: Is there a matching option? You can't set a select to a value that isn't one of its options.

Comment: Internally, the value of a select is stored as the index of the selected option. So when you assign to `.value`, it searches all the options for the matching one, and then sets `.selectedIndex` to that index.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that makes perfect sense. Your explanation triggered something in my head and I noticed there is no reason the value * can't be ALL instead which removes the need for the ELSE part.